# Handling variables based on environment in composer library

Tags: php, composer-php

**Context:**

I am developing a composer package of `type:library`. The package is a wrapper for an API.

I use Guzzle to do an API request to an url.

```
public function callMethodA() {
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res    = $client->request( 'GET', 'https://api.mydomain.com', [
        'getDetails' => [ 'methodA', 'parameter1' ]
    ] );
}
```

**My requirement:**

When the package is installed by my users in their project, I want the code to call production url - `https://api.mydomain.com`.

When I doing the package development on my local machine, I want the code to call my local url -  `http://api.mydomain.lcl`

**One way to do this:**

One alternative is I define constants and comment the development constant and un-comment the other constant, before I commit the code.

```
define('API_URL', 'http://api.mydomain.lcl');
//define('API_URL', 'http://api.mydomain.com'); DON'T FORGET TO UNCOMMENT THIS LINE AND COMMENT ABOVE LINE.

public function callMethodA() {
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res    = $client->request( 'GET', API_URL, [
        'getDetails' => [ 'methodA', 'parameter1' ]
    ] );
}
```

This alternative would work, but a risky alternative.

**Questions:**

1. What is a better way to handle variables based on composer's development environment (my local machine) and composer's deployment environment (package in my user's project).
2. If dotenv is a way to go, how do I release the env file on the deployment environment as my .env would be gitignored.

**Something to explain my setup:**
[image: Package Development]

Comment: Why not use `dotenv`? It's well documented, and "releasing" it to production simply means logging in there, editing that file, done. Or set the env variable using system-wide env variables on the production server

Comment: In composer case, I don't know the way to setup env variables in the application where my package would be composed in. I use dotenv for my projects, but just not sure how to use it in composer world.

Comment: Composer itself does not change anything, and using env variables in a live environment is well documented - what have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: I would have .env and .env.example. .env would be in gitignore. How the destination environment would get .env file for dotenv to load those variables? In normal cases, one would manually deploy .env on destination environment. In case of composer, I don’t have access to deploy that .env file in the destination environment.

Comment: How does Composer influence all this? What **exactly** keeps you from putting some file on the server, just like the rest of your application needs to be transferred? Or put the variables in the server configuration

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining it well. Added image in the questions to explain my setup. Package development company ABC doesn't have control on composer deployment environment in XYZ company's application.

Comment: I still don't get the problem: how is this related to Composer? Why not change the configuration of the target server, as you would have to do it for all stuff that is not under source control (like API keys, database credentials)?